# Error with simulation using INET in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I had been making simulations using INET with no problem, but suddenly I got an error and I don't know why. I don´t remember doing anything strange.

I decided to test with an empty workspace to see if I did something wrong in the one that I was working in. I installed INET with the dialog that appears whith the empty workspace. Then I created a new empty simulation project, and when I run it, I only get the message that says there is no network, but it works. But when I set INET as reference project in the properties of the empty project, it doesn't run and I get the following error messages:

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2019 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.5, build: 190529-d97ebbb173, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer


<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../inet/src//libINET_dbg.dll': No se encontró el proceso especificado

End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
Working directory: C:/Users/comec/Desktop/test/test/simulations
Command line: ../src/test_dbg.exe -m -n ../src;.;../../inet/src;../../inet/examples;../../inet/tutorials;../../inet/showcases --image-path=../../inet/images -l ../../inet/src/INET omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=;C:/Users/comec/Desktop/test/inet/src;C:\omnetpp-5.5\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.5\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.5\tools\win64\usr\bin;;C:/omnetpp-5.5/ide/jre/bin/server;C:/omnetpp-5.5/ide/jre/bin;C:/omnetpp-5.5/ide/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python37\;C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\dart-sass;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\comec\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\intelFPGA_lite\18.1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem;C:\Users\comec\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\comec\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32;C:\omnetpp-5.5\ide;
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=C:\omnetpp-5.5\images
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

By default INET is built in `release` mode, from the above output, it seems that your own project is set to be built in `debug` mode and that's why it fails during linking. The debug version of inet (libINET_dbg) was not built. You should either switch your own project to `release` or rebuild INET in debug mode, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I install INET in an empty workspace and open the properties of the inet project, I click on "C/C++ Build" and the "Configuration" field has the option "debug [Active]" selected. And also the /inet/src/libINET_dbg.dll does exists. Do I have to change the mode to debug anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

In case you get error that the library libnet.so has error with finding a symbol, it might be that your error is in the configuration in the main project.

You can go to run configuration, and change the Executable option to others -> add the path to your excutable, that is usually project/src/nameOfTheExecutable, example: "project1/src/test"